# Customizing the checkmo.phtml and email

Tags: magento-1.6, payment, email-templates, payment-methods

I've been customizing the labels in ../template/payment/form/checkmo.phtml since I don't want tu use it for check/cash but for another purpose - but the labels still figure as normal in the customers order email ? Should this be changed somewhere else perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need `../template/payment/info/checkmo.phtml`.

Comment: Thank you, didn't work at first from my template directory, But when I changed the content of the /base/default/../checkmo.phtml it did!

Comment: Should work from your theme also. You sure you copied it to the right path and also flushed caches?